# Convert "foreach" loop to:" for, while and do while"?

Tags: php, mysql

I´m trying to convert this foreach to all looops for printing the array from the msyql consult in screen.

````
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root" ,"" ,"base");
if($con->connect_error)
{
    die($con->mysqli_connect_error());
}

print_r ("conexion exitosa");

$sql = "SELECT code, name, grade FROM teachers WHERE status = 1 ";
$result = $con->query($sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); //array

**foreach ($result as $row) //array as value
    {
        print_r($row); //print value
    }**
?> ```
````

Comment: @ASDFGerte Right. I removed that tag; thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what you would like to do? Your code could work only if the result has more than 1 row. What loop do you need?

Comment: I want to print the variable $row in every possible loop, but only the array.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to loop on the result multiple times or just that you would like to see how the same code can be written using other loops?

Comment: If you have a problem with explaining in English what you want, could you use translate.google.com to translate it into English? We need better description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more step in order to convert the MySQL returned row(s) into an array.

`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  var_dump($row);
}`

You can also echo each element from a row. For example:

`echo $row['myfield'];` inside your while loop.

Comment: Could you explain how does this help and what problem does it solve?

Comment: My understanding is that he'd like to be able to easily manipulate the results. It could be a for or while loop. The solution proposed here is basic and simple but it solves his problem to the extent I understood it. `mysqli_query()` will return an object that is harder to manipulate. Hence, the extra step? Not sure I understood your question.

Comment: That's the thing, your loop is doing exactly the same things as the loop in question.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed now that he is converting it to an array before looping, hadn't seen that before. So I can't answer your question to be honest with you but you are correct, this solution doesn't do anything else other than an example on how to echo individual values from the row.

Comment: Yeah this is only for academic porpuses, I don´t want to do anything especial with it. I´m having trouble with the "for" loop, can anyone help me here? ty.

Comment: @CarlosMtz What do you mean you have trouble with `for` loop? Show us what you tried.